# Passing data from child to parent after exec in Perl

Tags: perl, ipc

I would like to call a perl program `child.pl` in another perl program `parent.pl`, and hope to pass data from `child.pl` to `parent.pl` and print these data by `parent.pl`.  `system("perl child.pl")` may not work, since parent.pl would will do nothing until `child.pl` completes. I read [the online doc of perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html), it seems `pipe()` and `fork()` could match some of my needs, but I failed to find a method to pass data from child process to parent after `exec`. Here's the code of `parent.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

pipe(FROM_CHILD, TO_PARENT);  

$pid = fork();  

if ($pid == 0) {  
    # We're in the child process.  
    close(FROM_CHILD);  
    # Send data to parent.  
    print TO_PARENT "Hello, parent\n"; #  I can pass data to parent before exec
    exec("perl child.pl");             #  But how what should I do after exec, in child.pl?
    exit(0);  # Terminate child.  
} 
elsif (undef $pid) {  
    print "Not defined: means an error.";  
} 
else {  
    # Parent process.  
    close(TO_PARENT);  
    $data = <FROM_CHILD>;  
    print "From child: $data\n";  
    $id = wait();  
    print "Child $id is dead.\n";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be helpful:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open (my $child, "-|","./child.pl") or die("$!");
while (<$child>) {
  print "P: $_";
}
close($child);
```

open function, [from perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> For three or more arguments if MODE is |- , the filename is
>   interpreted as a command to which output is to be piped, and **if MODE
>   is -|** , the filename is interpreted as a command that pipes output to
>   us.

If you don't want to touch the stdout then you need cooperation from the child and then you can use named pipes:

**parent.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl;
use POSIX;
my $fpath = '.named.pipe';

mkfifo($fpath, 0666) or die "mknod $!";
system("perl child.pl &");
sysopen(my $fifo, $fpath, O_RDONLY) or die "sysopen: $!";

while (<$fifo>) {
  print "P: $_";
}
close($fifo);
unlink($fifo);
```

**child.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl;
use POSIX;

my $fpath = '.named.pipe';
sysopen(my $fifo, $fpath, O_WRONLY) or die "sysopen: $!";
print "screen hello\n";
print $fifo "parent hello\n";
close($fifo);
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer, but what if the child.pl have other output to the standard output? For example, child.pl have two functions: `print_data_to_screen` to screen and `print_data_to_parent` to parent.

Comment: Can you use stderr for printing to screen?

Comment: I'm afraid no, stdout and stderr are used for different purpose in child.pl. Could I pass the pipe to child.pl and use it in child.pl? I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want. And I also found an alternative of named pipe for Windows platform (Win32::Pipe) since my code should run on both platforms.